# How can i resize main window from slot in my class?

Tags: c++, qt

It's easy to do in constructor, but how about resize in slot?
In constructor i just make this :

```
MyDialogWindow::MyDialogWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyDialogWindow)
{ 
.....
    int x=this->width()*1;
    int y=this->height()*0.5;
    this->setFixedSize(x,y);
....
}
```

but same didn't work in slot :

```
void MyDialogWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
int x=this->width()*1;
int y=this->height()*1;
this->setFixedSize(x,y);

}
```

It seem that i don't have object of main window in methods, so how it must be?

Comment: have you tried setGeometry?

Comment: Are you sure your slot is called?

Comment: Where is this main window?

Comment: Also, `this->width()*1 == this->width()`. So what are you expecting to happen, if you're giving it the same size it currently has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [QWidget::setGeometry](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#geometry-prop).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `this->updateGeometry()` after `setFixedSize` to signal a re-layout of your widget:

```
void MyDialogWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int x=this->width()*1;
    int y=this->height()*1;//make sure something actually changes with the size though
    this->setFixedSize(x,y);
    this->updateGeometry();
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to change the size at all by multiplying the current width and height by 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
void MyDialogWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int x = this->width()  * 2;
    int y = this->height() * 2;
    this->setFixedSize( x , y );
    this->updateGeometry( );
}
```

This should work as `this->width( ) * 1` will always be the same size. Ofc you won't see a difference.

Better to make `x` and `y` global in your class and set the width and height there and just assign the new size when you click the button so you don't have it multiply every time you click the button:

```
int x = ui->pushButton.width()  * 2;
int y = ui->pushButton.height() * 2;

void MyDialogWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    this->setFixedSize( x , y );
    this->updateGeometry( );
}
```

Comment: @ratojakuf Yes because this will double the size every time you click on the button you need to handle that accordingly or set a maximum size.

Comment: It's work but with warnings. When i use this code :      


`void MyDialogWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    static bool open = true;
    int y;

    if(open)
        y = this->height()  * 2;
    else
        y = this->height() / 2;

    this->setFixedHeight( y );
    this->updateGeometry( );

    open = !open;
}`
  
     
After two clicks i get console message :  
`QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Attempt to set a size (338x170) violating the constraints(0x170 - 16777215x85) on window QWidgetWindow/'MyDialogWindowWindow'.`